# FileWriter is not writing into a file

Tags: java, file

I have below code

```
try
{
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\temp\\test.txt");
    fileWriter.write("Hi this is sasi This test writing");
    fileWriter.append("test");
}
catch(IOException ioException)
{
    ioException.printStackTrace();
}
```

After executing it, the file is created successfully, but the created file is empty.

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Try a flush after writing.

Comment: try to flush the writer. By default it print the result the value only the buffer is full or writer is closed.

Comment: Side note: consider to use the NIO.2 File API (introduced in Java SE 7) instead of FileWriter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You must close the `FileWriter`, otherwise it won't flush the current buffer. You can call the `flush` method directly..

```
fileWriter.flush()
fileWriter.close()
```

You don't need to use the `flush` method if you are closing the file. The `flush` can be used for example if your program runs for a while and outputs something in a file and you want to check it elsewhere.

Comment: Make sure you're calling close() in the finally-clause. Best to use try-with-resources.

Comment: For me it was that I had the relative pathname of the file. Getting the absolute path made it work.

Answer (score 4):

Closing was missing. Hence not the last buffered data was not written to disk.

Closing also happens with try-with-resources. Even when an exception would be thrown. Also a `flush` before `close` is not needed, as a close flushes all buffered data to file.

```
try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\temp\\test.txt"))
{
    fileWriter.write("Hi this is sasi This test writing");
    fileWriter.append("test");
}
catch (IOException ioException)
{
    ioException.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to close the `filewriter` else the current buffer will not flush and will not allow you to write to the file.

```
fileWriter.flush(); //just makes sure that any buffered data is written to disk
fileWriter.close(); //flushes the data and indicates that there isn't any more data.
```

From  the Javadoc

> Close the stream, flushing it first. Once a stream has been closed,
>   further write() or flush() invocations will cause an IOException to be
>   thrown. Closing a previously-closed stream, however, has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Hey

{
    public static void main(String ar[])throws IOException
    {

            File file = new File("c://temp//Hello1.txt");
            // creates the file
            file.createNewFile();
            // creates a FileWriter Object
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file); 
            // Writes the content to the file
            writer.write("This\n is\n an\n example\n"); 
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
  try
    {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\temp\\test.txt");
        fileWriter.write("Hi this is sasi This test writing");
        fileWriter.append("test");
        fileWriter.flush(); // empty buffer in the file
        fileWriter.close(); // close the file to allow opening by others applications
    }
    catch(IOException ioException)
    {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
```